# Ant <exec> output not captured in property

Tags: ant

I am trying to get the output of an Ant execution command into an output property and echo that property. We should be able to view the output of the command. I have used the below code, but I am not able to view the output of the Ant execution.

```
<exec executable="${exe.baroverride}"
      spawn="false"
      failonerror="true"
>
    <redirector outputproperty="baroverride.out"
        errorproperty="baroverride.err"/>
</exec>
<logmsg message="Bar Override Output for the bar file ${iib.build.target.bar.filename} ${baroverride.out}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no `<logmsg>` task included with Ant. `<logmsg>` may be from a custom `<macrodef>` or `<taskdef>`. We won't be able to help you with how `<logmsg>` works unless you provide the code for it.

Second, the `<redirector>` splits the output into two properties...

```
 <redirector outputproperty="baroverride.out"
     errorproperty="baroverride.err"/>
```

...however, the `<logmsg>` call only references `baroverride.out`...

```
<logmsg message="... ${baroverride.out}"/>
```

If `<exec>` wrote to `baroverride.err`, the above `<logmsg>` call won't show it.

Consider deleting the `<redirector>` altogether and use the `outputproperty` attribute of `<exec>` instead...

```
<exec executable="${exe.baroverride}"
      spawn="false"
      failonerror="true"
      outputproperty="baroverride.out"
/>
<echo>baroverride.out: ${baroverride.out}</echo>
```

Comment: Hi Chad thanks for taking your time to comment on this thread. PFB the code for the log message we have been using in our ant macro definition  `<macrodef name="logmsg">
  <attribute name="message" />
  <attribute name="level" default="info" />
  <!-- Echo the time ... -->
  <sequential>
   <tstamp>
    <format property="logtime" pattern="dd-mm-yy_HH-mm-ss" />
   </tstamp>
   <echo level="@{level}" message="@{level},${logtime},@{message}" />
  </sequential>
 </macrodef>`